# How to quote original message in reply using Gmail API in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, reply

I'm using the Gmail API in Google Apps Script to send a reply to the first (original) message of a thread. The code works fine and sends the reply in the same thread for both the sender and recipients using Gmail. However, when the recipient's email service is not Gmail and doesn't provide threading or conversation grouping, the recipient receives the follow-up email (reply) as a separate email without the body of the original message. In other words, the reply doesn't quote the original message.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm currently using:

```
    var thread = GmailApp.getThreadById(existingThreadId);
var messages = thread.getMessages();

if (messages.length > 0) {
  var originalMessage = messages[0];
  var recipientEmail = originalMessage.getTo();
  var senderEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var messageId = originalMessage.getHeader("Message-ID");
  var data = [
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
    `In-Reply-To: ${messageId}\n`,
    `Subject: Re:${originalMessage.getSubject()}\n`,
    `From: ${senderEmail}\n`,
    `To: ${recipientEmail}\n\n`,
    "This is a reminder for previous email",
  ].join("");
  var draftReplyRequestBody = {
    message: {
      threadId: existingThreadId,
      raw: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(data),
    },
  };
  var draftReplyResponse = Gmail.Users.Drafts.create(draftReplyRequestBody, "me");
  var draftReplyId = draftReplyResponse.id;
  var sendReplyParams = { id: draftReplyId };

  Gmail.Users.Drafts.send(sendReplyParams, "me");
}
```

Is there a way to modify this code to include the quoting of the original message in the reply, similar to how Gmail UI quotes the original message in a reply? I want the recipient to see the original message and its attachments within the reply. This way, Gmail users will receive the reply in the same thread with a quote of the main email, while non-Gmail users may receive it as a separate email but with the original email quote.

[image]

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `However, when the recipient's email service is not Gmail and doesn't provide threading or conversation grouping, the recipient receives the follow-up email (reply) as a separate email without the body of the original message. In other words, the reply doesn't quote the original message.`.

Comment: And also, I cannot understand `Is there a way to modify this code to include the quoting of the original message in the reply, similar to how Gmail UI quotes the original message in a reply? I want the recipient to see the original message and its attachments within the reply.`. Can I ask you about the detail of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, sure. I edited the question and added an image as an example of Gmail UI which has a reply email structure that contains the quotation of the previous email below the reply email body. 
About your first question, there are some other email platforms such as "Roundcube" which do not provide grouping of emails as a conversation ( threads in Gmail) and they show every reply as a separate email with a quotation of previous email.  Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I guessed that when you reply an email, you wanted to include the previous email. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, for example, the email is sent from user "A" to user "B", and user "B" reply an email (You want to send it as a reply including the previous email?), and also, user "A" is sent to user "B", and when the user "B" is sent it as a reply, you want to include the previous 3 emails? I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike
 Yes. Actually, it is similar to the reply system of the Gmail Web. You can try it in gmail web and check its reply system. When we send a reply to an email in gmail web, it shows a three-dot button (like the image in my question) at the end of the reply message and if we click on that button it shows the time, sender, subject and body of the previous email.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, you want to include the current all messages in the thread when an email is reply. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike No there is no need to include all of the thread messages. Only include the message we send a reply on it. Suppose there are messages A, B, C, D,... in the thread, we decide to reply to the message of C, so I want to only include the message C (as a quotation) in the reply email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following reply,

> No there is no need to include all of the thread messages. Only include the message we send a reply on it. Suppose there are messages A, B, C, D,... in the thread, we decide to reply to the message of C, so I want to only include the message C (as a quotation) in the reply email.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = [
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
  `In-Reply-To: ${messageId}\n`,
  `Subject: Re:${originalMessage.getSubject()}\n`,
  `From: ${senderEmail}\n`,
  `To: ${recipientEmail}\n\n`,
  "This is a reminder for previous email",
].join("");
```

#### To:

```
var emailBody = "This is a reminder for previous email\n\n" + messages.pop().getPlainBody().replace(/^/gm, "> ");
var data = [
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
  `In-Reply-To: ${messageId}\n`,
  `Subject: Re:${originalMessage.getSubject()}\n`,
  `From: ${senderEmail}\n`,
  `To: ${recipientEmail}\n\n`,
  emailBody,
].join("");
```

- By this modification, only the last message in the thread is added to the text body.

#### Note:

- This answer is for your question. In your question, only the text body is used. So, I proposed the modified script using the text body. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It works but there is an issue that it only adds the last message of the thread. Can you modify the code in order to add specific message of the thread?  for example the first message of the thread or the message which we want to send reply on it.

Comment: @Hamed Thank you for replying. About `it only adds the last message of the thread.`, I understood like that from your reply. I apologize for this. And, about `Can you modify the code in order to add specific message of the thread?`, in that case, please modify `messages.pop().getPlainBody()` to `messages[n].getPlainBody()`. By modifying the value of `n`, you can retrieve the specific message in the thread.

Comment: is it possible to use html format of the message[n] instead of using getPlainBody() ?  I  used getPlainBody() and seems it retrieves the plain text of the message and does not preserve its paragraph formatting.

Comment: in addition as you can see in the picture attached to the question, There is a sentence like "On Wed, July 5, 2023 at 11:13 AM, Hamed <XXXXXX@gmail.com> wrote:". can we modify the code to mention sentence like this in above the every quotation?

Comment: @Hamed Thank you for replying. About your 2nd question of `is it possible to use html format of the message[n] instead of using getPlainBody() ?`, in your question, I think that it's yes. The HTML body can be retrieved by `getBody()` method of Class GmailMessage. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getBody())

Comment: @Hamed About your 3rd question of `in addition as you can see in the picture attached to the question, There is a sentence like "On Wed, July 5, 2023 at 11:13 AM, Hamed <XXXXXX@gmail.com> wrote:". can we modify the code to mention sentence like this in above the every quotation?`, I think that it's yes. The date can be retrieved by `getDate()` method of Class GmailMessage. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getDate())